# SQL: практика

Tags: mysql, sql

Часто замечаю за собой что иду на ХешКод чтобы за меня сделали какой нибудь немного сложный SQL-запрос.

Где потренироваться, или что почитать чтобы быть более умным и самому много делать?

Документацию не могу особо понять.

Comment: Когда возникает необходимость написать какой-нибудь немного сложный SQL-запрос - пишите его сами. Выкручивайтесь, ищите ответы и всё станет на свои места.

Comment: Так не знаю же как писать. А искать на трэш-форумах с такими же ответами - сложновато.

Comment: поищите реальные вопросы которые задают на собеседованиях, потом уже ищите ответы на них, делайте тестовые задания. будет цель - найдутся и средства

Comment: @exec, купите книгу Кузнецова, Симдянова, практика будет до последней главы =) и MySQL / SQL рецепты. Вторый две лучше читать после хорошей базы знаний. Ваш уровень быстро поднимется, правда читать нужно будет много.

Answer (score 4):

Потренироваться можно [здесь](http://sql-ex.ru).
Только внимательно прочтите правила при регистрации.

Answer (score 2):

Когда возникла серьезная потребность - купил это: [SQL. Сборник рецептов](http://www.symbol.ru/alphabet/608269.html)

Прошло почти 4 года, а я понимаю, что книга и последующее применение методов из книги в  рабочем проекте смогли помочь мне в становлении. Теперь с SQL-запросами на "ты".

Одним словом - советую.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как потренироваться, но здесь приведено много примеров по каждому запросу. По аналогии можно составить свой [link text](http://sql-language.ru/)

Comment: Ядерный сайт конечно. Не содержание, а реклама...

Answer (score 0):

сначала попробуйте разбить ваш запрос на самые простые запросы, 1 запрос - 1 таблица. Далее начинайте их связывать по полям. и каждую связку не ленитесь - тестируйте - чтоб ошибки можно было сразу найти.

Еще совет - возмите и просто напишите на русс ком свой запрос (если с мануалами у вас пока плохо) - "Выбираем поле 1 из таблицы 1, поле 2 из таблицы 2 и т д"